# Convert a large number of CSV files to parquet files

Tags: csv, apache-spark, parquet

I have a large number of CSV files that need to be converted to parquet files, using pyspark.
One CSV is to one Parquet.

Input: csv files:

```
000.csv
001.csv
002.csv
...
```

Output: qarquet files:

```
000.parquet
001.parquet
002.parquet
...
```

My current solution is:

```
for each_csv in same_folder:
   df = spark.read.csv(each_csv, header = True)
   df.write.parquet(output_folder)
```

The for loop is expensive. Is there any way I can utilize spark to do the batch processing? 
e.g.

spark.read.csv(same_folder/*).write.parquet(output_folder/*)

Based on the QuickSilver's answer, here is my PySpark version:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("csv_to_parquet").getOrCreate()

# Read csv files into a single data frame and add a column of input file names: 
baseDf = spark.read.csv("input_folder/*.csv").withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())

# Convert file names into a list: 
filePathInfo = baseDf.select("input_file_name").distinct().collect() 
filePathInfo_array = list(map(lambda row: row.input_file_name, filePathInfo))

# Write to parquet:  
map(lambda csvFileName: baseDf.filter(col("input_file_name").endsWith(csvFileName)).write.mode('overwrite').parquet(f'output_folder/{csvFileName}'), filePathInfo_array)
```

Comment: Do all you csv fall in same folder ? Loading all the CSV in a single go and filter them based on file name would be more efficient way I think

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps for avoiding multiple file loads in Spark by following below steps,

1. Load the dataframe using source csv folder
2. column `input_file_name` which records source file name
3. Collect the file names into a List
4. Iterate over the file name list

In the file name list loop,

1. Filter dataframe by file name
2. Write to respective file

Sudo working code in scala

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object ReadWriteToRespCsv {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate;

    val baseDf = spark.read.csv("src/main/resources/same_folder/*.csv")
      //Add a column `input_file_name` which records source file name
      .withColumn("input_file_name",input_file_name())

    //Collect the file names into a List
    val filePathInfo = baseDf.select("input_file_name").distinct()
      .map(row=>Paths.get(row.getString(0)).getFileName.toString)(Encoders.STRING).collect()

    //Iterate for file name list
    filePathInfo.foreach(csvFileName => {
      baseDf
        //Filter dataframe by file name
        .filter(col("input_file_name").endsWith(csvFileName) )
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        //Write to respective file
        .parquet(s"src/main/resources/output_folder/${csvFileName}")
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: The code works but the current problem is the data get shifted to a wrong column, because every CSV file has slightly different columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use globbing pattern to select the files or you can provide a list of files.

If I have two files in folders `/tmp/file1_csv/file1.csv` and `/tmp/file2_csv/file2.csv`, I can use following

```scala
spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/tmp/file*_csv/*.csv")
```

Alternatively, if you have weird paths, you can also use overloaded version of `csv` method.

```scala
val paths = "/dir1/,/dir2/,/dir3/"
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(paths.split(","): _*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks a good way to read csv files in batch. Then, how can I convert each of them to parquet?

Comment: Once you've got them in dataframe, you can do whatever you want. You can use `df.write.mode("append").parquet("/path/to/hdfs/")`

Comment: Oh, sorry, i think I should've made the question more clear. I want to convert each csv from the same folder to parquet. One CSV is for one parquet.

Comment: I just updated my question to make it more clear. :)